# How to convert 'const wchar*' to 'const char*' on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, char, constants, wchar

Is there a elegant way to convert 'const wchar *' to 'const char *' on Mac OS X?

Kat

Answer (score 2):

Use `wcstombs`:

size_t wcstombs(char *dest, const wchar_t *src, size_t n);

Make sure you have your locale set appropriately.

Comment: It took me two reads to recognize that it is wcs to mbs, and has nothing to do with tombs :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine why one would be using wchar_t on OS X, but here's how it can be done in standard C++:

```
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>,wchar_t> convert;

    wchar_t const *ws = L"Steve Nash";
    std::string s = convert.to_bytes(ws);
    char const *cs = s.c_str();
}
```